# check if there is a div that has the words `some text` and has the `i` tag

Tags: xpath, selenium

I have a class:

```
<div class = "abc def">
    <i style="...."></i>
    some text 2
</div>

<div class = "abc def">
    <i></i>
    some text
</div>

<div class = "abc def">
    1 some text
</div>
```

how can I check if there is a div that has the words `some text` and there is the `i` tag in this div?

for this example, I have to get the first and the second div. the third div doesn't have the `i` tag, so then I won't get him.

I think it should be:

```
elements = driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[contains(text(), 'some text')]));
if (elements.length > 0) {
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
       if (elements[i].find('<i') != null) {
             alert('the item: ' + i + 'is found');
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not grab all the "i" tags and then filter them out by some text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath expression more or less equals the natural language version:

```
//div[contains(., 'some text') and i]
```

If the `<i/>` tag may be contained within other elements, use `.//i` instead. In most cases you want to use `.` instead of `text()`, this joins all text nodes and scans the combined result, so `<em>some</em> text` would be matched, too.